# Como crear un XML en un objeto que tiene listas en c#

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy trabajando en un reconocedor AFD y necesito crear un archivo XML, tengo este un Objeto llamado Automata.

```
[Serializable]
    public class Automata
    {
        public List<int> estado_Q { get; set; }
        public List<char> alfabeto_X { get; set; }
        public List<Transicion> ftrans_t { get; set; }
        public int estadoInicio_qo { get; set; }
        public List<int> estadosFinales_F { get; set; }

        public Automata(List<int> Q, List<char> X, List<Transicion> T, int qo, List<int> F)
        {
            estado_Q = Q;
            alfabeto_X = X;
            ftrans_t = T;
            estadoInicio_qo = qo;
            estadosFinales_F = F;

        }

    }
```

```
[Serializable]
    public class Transicion
    {
        public int fromEstado { get; set; }
        public char leeyendo { get; set; }
        public int untilEstado { get; set; }


        public Transicion(int iEstado, char leer, int fEstado)
        {
            fromEstado = iEstado;
            leeyendo = leer;
            untilEstado = fEstado;
        }
    }
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Clases.Automata au = new Clases.Automata();

            var automatalista = new Clases.Automata();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clases.Automata>));

            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Temp\\File.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, automatalista);
            }

        }
```

estoy usando el siguiente codigo pero me retorno un error 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Create Xml Object.Program no es accesible por el nivel de protección. Sólo se pueden procesar tipos públicos.'

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que definir un constructor sin parametros

Ademas define un `type` como `List<Automata>` para serializar, debes pasar una instancia de ese tipo de objeto

Si defines las clases de esta forma

```
[Serializable]
public class Automata
{
    public List<int> estado_Q { get; set; }
    public List<char> alfabeto_X { get; set; }
    public List<Transicion> ftrans_t { get; set; }
    public int estadoInicio_qo { get; set; }
    public List<int> estadosFinales_F { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Transicion
{
    public int fromEstado { get; set; }
    public char leeyendo { get; set; }
    public int untilEstado { get; set; }

}
```

Podrias implementar la serializacion usando

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Automata au = new Automata();
        au.estadoInicio_qo = 10;

        var automatalista = new List<Automata>();
        automatalista.Add(au);

        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Automata>));
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, automatalista);

            memStream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStream);
            string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(xmlString);
        }

    }
}
```

Cambie el `TextWriter` por `MemoryStream` asi se puede visualizar el string del xml que se genera, pero puedes volver esa parte a la original que tienes para generar el archivo